# SQL SELECT STATEMENT FOR TODAY

Tags: sql

I have been battling for two days now, please could someone give me a bit of assistance on below. I am trying to select data where a date field/column must equal today's date.

```
SELECT * 
FROM stock 
WHERE DATE(PREVSELLPRICE1DATE)=DATE(now());
```

Please assist if you can, I need to rollout this report.

Comment: which dbms  are you using ?

Comment: When it comes to date/time, too many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant. So tag the dbms you're using!

Comment: What is the Problem with your query?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is better not to manipulate DATE column using functions like TRUNC to mach the date without hour precision (matching year-month-day), it recommended for performance to use something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM stock 
WHERE PREVSELLPRICE1DATE between trunc(sysdate) and trunc(sysdate+1)
```

this way you'll compare for the required day only + the TRUNC function will be applied only 2 times instead of on each row.

Answer (score 0):

For sql server below is fine:

```
SELECT * 
FROM stock 
WHERE CAST(PREVSELLPRICE1DATE as date) = CAST(GETDATE() as date)
```

Below script

```
select cast(getdate() as date)
```

will give you result:

```
2017-06-29
```